# Como arreglar el fondo en modo oscuro de outlook al implementar html

Tags: html, css, diseño, frontend, outlook

Estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de un template en windows 10 en visual code y tengo que colocar a una `<tr class="keep-white">` un background con el siguiente color:

`background-color: #013a71`

El tema esta en que outlook con el cambio de temas tiene algunas incompatibilidades y para este caso el modo claro funciona perfecto pero al cambiar al modo oscuro el color se cambia.

he probado lo siguiente y no a funcionado

```
<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
<style>
tr {
    background-color: #013a71 !important; 
    color: #ffffff !important; 
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

encontre una web que hablaba algo sobre el tema pero solo me dio la solución para las letras

```
<!--[if gte mso 16]> 
<style> 
.keep-white { 
mso-style-textfill-type:gradient; 
mso-style-textfill-fill-gradientfill-stoplist:"0 \#FFFFFF 0 100000\,100000 \#FFFFFF 0 100000"; 
color:#000000 !important; 

mso-background-color: #013a71 !important; 
} 
</style>
```

esta es la web:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/how-to-fix-outlook-dark-mode-problems--cms-37718t

en otro sitio encontré algo relacionado
(https://medium.com/emails-hteumeuleu/dealing-with-outlook-coms-dark-mode-dd56a1c0fdbc)
y me puse a probar cambios con los gradiantes y investigando mas sobre el uso de mso y vml pero no he podido solucionarlo aun por eso espero que alguien conozca alguna solución se lo agradecería.